# Combine characters to create an even higher one?

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to combine characters from chr(0) - chr(255) to create a character above chr(256) is it possible to achieve this? here is a basic code of what I am doing:

```
import pyclip

rand_char = [random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(random.randint(1,4))]

# what to do here?
combined_char = create_higher_char(rand_char)

pyclip.copy(combined_char)
```

Basically for example you can get chr(1499) via : `'\xd7\x9b'`

```
>>> chr(1499)
'כ'
>>> chr(1499).encode()
b'\xd7\x9b'
```

So when I get `'\xd7\x9b'` on rand_char I should be able to copy `chr(1499)` instead of `'\xd7\x9b'` which has a value of :

```
>>> [ord(x) for x in '\xd7\x9b']
[215, 155]
```

I tried creating a list of possible combinations of encoded characters but some characters do not have **.encode()**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

How is it possible to get the value `1499` from `[215, 155]`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You might need to do some reading about Unicode, encodings (like UTF-8), and the difference between `str` and `bytes`. To start, `b'\xd7\x9b'` is not the same as `'\xd7\x9b'`. If it helps, for 1499 specifically, you can do `bytes([215, 155]).decode('utf-8')`, but that doesn't really answer your overall question because other combinations are invalid, like `[215, 61]` for example. Maybe you actually want something more like `rand_char = random.randint(0, sys.maxunicode)`?

Comment: I am aware that I would be able to use randomize ints then parse them to characters, but I need this kind of system specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you obtain by using `.encode` have nothing to do with the values you create a char with by using the `chr()` call:

The second one takes one number and uses it as the [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) for the character: this is a numeric space from 32 to 2**20 (but with empty spaces declared as not used, or reserved for future use) where a number corresponds to a character.

When you call `.encode()` without passing a parameter, Python will use the [`utf-8` encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is a variable length encoding - utf-8 byte sequences for characters **do not correspond** to the codepoints: rather there are a set of prefix-bytes that indicate if a character is encoded in 2, 3 or 4 bytes - or, if it lies in the 0-128 range, it is represented as a single byte
(for these characters, which correspond to the ASCII characters, and only these, the utf-8 representation will match the codepoint).

So, now you know all of this, to get from the sequence `b'\xd7\x9b'` to the codepoint 1499, you have first to *decode* the bytes from their utf-8 representation, and then call the `ord()` built-in function with the resulting character to get its codepoint. `ord()` will always operate on *strings* (never on bytes) of one single character, and is the converse call to `chr()`:

```
In [18]: b'\xd7\x9b'.decode("utf-8")
Out[18]: 'כ'

In [19]: ord(b'\xd7\x9b'.decode("utf-8"))
Out[19]: 1499
```

If you want to get byte strings matching the character code-points, one alternative is to use the `utf-32` encoding: it will always use 4 bytes per character, and each 4 bytes, when transformed to an int, will match the codepoint for that char:

```
In [26]: a = 'כ'

In [27]: a.encode("utf-32le")
Out[27]: b'\xdb\x05\x00\x00'

In [28]: int.from_bytes(a.encode("utf-32le"), "little")
Out[28]: 1499
```